# resharper: loading html resources in js unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, resharper, chutzpah

For my .NET solution, I've created some javascript unit tests with QUnit that run perfectly from console with the Chutzpah test runner. The tests use JQuery to load external resources (html files) stored in a subfolder and execute dom manipulations on them.

However, when trying to run the same tests from the Resharper 7 unit tests console in Visual Studio, no external resources is loaded. Apparently, Resharper is serving tests from its own custom web server that is returning an empty response for every HTTP request.

Has anybody found a way to solve this problem, by means of configuration or additional tools?

Comment: I'm facing this same problem, for me the problem is that when running the tests resharper assings a random port, so when trying to load html files I'm making a cross domain request, since I need to get the resources from a specific port. did you managed to load the files?